# lighttpd reverse proxy - all responses are blank pages

Tags: reverse-proxy, lighttpd

I have a lighttpd server (1.4.35) configured as a reverse proxy in front of a Play Framework (v.1.2.5.3) application running on the same server and it is working fine. Here's the lighttpd config:

```
$SERVER["socket"] == ":8009" {
        proxy.debug = 1
        proxy.server = ("" => (("host" => "127.0.0.1", "port" => 9000 )))
}
```

I want to move the Play app to another server but when I try to access it via lighttpd, *any* requests I make are returning w/ status=200, content-length=0 & a blank page. The new lighttpd config is:

```
$SERVER["socket"] == ":8009" {
        proxy.debug = 1
        proxy.server = ("" => (("host" => "10.10.1.102", "port" => 9000 )))
}
```

I have tested that the Play application is accessible from the server lighttpd is running on (e.g. `wget http://10.10.1.102:9000` from the lighttpd server returns the correct content).

Lighttpd's proxy.debug output is:

```
when accessing locally:
    2014-12-14 07:43:56: (mod_proxy.c.1144) proxy - start
    2014-12-14 07:43:56: (mod_proxy.c.1185) proxy - ext found
    2014-12-14 07:43:56: (mod_proxy.c.1319) proxy - found a host 127.0.0.1 9000
    2014-12-14 07:43:56: (mod_proxy.c.398) connect delayed: 13
    2014-12-14 07:43:56: (mod_proxy.c.1000) proxy: fdevent-out 1
    2014-12-14 07:43:56: (mod_proxy.c.1029) proxy - connect - delayed success
    2014-12-14 07:43:56: (mod_proxy.c.969) proxy: fdevent-in 4
    2014-12-14 07:43:56: (mod_proxy.c.667) proxy - have to read: 2785
    2014-12-14 07:43:56: (mod_proxy.c.969) proxy: fdevent-in 4
    2014-12-14 07:43:56: (mod_proxy.c.667) proxy - have to read: 0

when accessing 10.10.1.102:9000 
    2014-12-14 07:42:42: (mod_proxy.c.1144) proxy - start
    2014-12-14 07:42:42: (mod_proxy.c.1185) proxy - ext found
    2014-12-14 07:42:42: (mod_proxy.c.1319) proxy - found a host 10.10.1.102 9000
    2014-12-14 07:42:42: (mod_proxy.c.398) connect delayed: 10
    2014-12-14 07:42:42: (mod_proxy.c.1000) proxy: fdevent-out 1
    2014-12-14 07:42:42: (mod_proxy.c.1029) proxy - connect - delayed success
    2014-12-14 07:42:42: (mod_proxy.c.969) proxy: fdevent-in 4
    2014-12-14 07:42:42: (mod_proxy.c.667) proxy - have to read: 0
```

Any ideas why lighttpd isn't getting any content from the second server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who find this question and have the same problem .... I switched to nginx and had it running in 15 minutes. Not sure why lighttpd wasn't able to do the same.

Comment: Had the same problem and also switched to nginx. Now everything works as it should.